# Prove $A$ is compact if $A\cup B$ is compact and the closure of $A$ does not intersect $B$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If $A\cup B$ is compact, why $A$ is also compact if the closure of $A$ does not intersect $b$?

I can understand that if $A,B$ are compact then also the union of them. But, why we have to add the condition: the closure of $A$ does not intersect $b$ to prove $A$ is compact if $A\cup B$ is compact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not true. Consider $A=[0,1), B=\{1\}.$

Comment: @zhw. I suspect he might be asking if $A \cup B$ is compact and $A,B$ are disjoint, then at least one of $A,B$ are compact.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Sorry for my mistake, it should be the closure of A.

Comment: @zhw It should be the closure of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let us see why the claim is true. Suppose $\bar{A}\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B$ is compact. We want to prove that $A$ is compact.  To this end,  let ${U_i}_{i\in I}$ be an arbitrary cover of $A.$ Note that $B\subseteq \bar{A}^c,$ and therefore $\{U_i:i\in I\}\cup \{\bar{A}^c\}$ is an open cover of $A\cup B.$ From the compactness of $A\cup B,$ It must have a finite sub-cover. (Possibly) Discarding the $\bar{A}^c,$ you obtain a finite refinement of original cover for $A.$ This proves that $A$ is compact.

As @zhw already pointed in the comment that the conclusion is false if you only assume $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ This answers the question which you asked (Namely, why is the stronger condition required). It is also instructive to look at where the above proof fails if you only assume $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ It still holds that $B\subseteq A^c,$ but the problem is that $A^c$ may not be open.

Answer (score 1):

$A,B,$ are subsets of $X$. Consider an open  cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $A$ by open subsets of $A$, we can write $U_i=V_i\cap X$ where $V_i$ open in $X$.

Write $W_i=V_i\cap (A\cup B)$, $(W_i)_{i\in I}\cup (X-\bar A)\cap (A\cup B)$ is an open cover of $A\cup B$ and thus has a finite cover $W_1,...,W_n, (X-\bar A)\cap (A\cup B)$, $U_1,...,U_n$ is a finite cover of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If either $A$ or $B$ is empty then this is trivial. Therefore, assume neither are empty.

Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $A$. Then , $U_i, \overline{A}^c$ is an open cover of $A \cup B$, which has a finite subcover. There is a subset $J$ of the index set $I$ that is finite, and  $(\cup_{j \in J} U_j ) \cup \overline{A}^c$ is an open cover of $A \cup B$, and therefore an open cover of $A$. Since $\overline{A}^c$ is disjoint from $A$, every point in $A$ must be contained in $\cup_{j \in J} U_j $. Therefore, $\cup_{j \in J} U_j $ is a finite subcover of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If so then $A$ is closed in compact subspace $A\cup B$ of $X$. Since closed subsets of compact spaces are compact (exercise) $A$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But $A$ seems not closed because $A$ is not $ \overline{A} $.

Comment: Umm…$A=\overline{A}\cap(A\cup B)$ therefore closed in $A\cup B$ in the sense of subspace topology.

Comment: Got it! thank you!